# MS SQL - Truncation Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run an update/insert statement for a particular table I return the following error:

*** ERROR 8152 ***(rc -1) : SQLSTATE = 22001
Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0
String or binary data would be truncated.

I've manually gone through the table I'm trying to update to see if there are any values greater than the max varchar allowed for the column and could not find anything each using the following script:

```
select max(len(COLUMN_NAME)) from TABLE_NAME
```

Is there a way to query the db for values in all columns that overrun the max allowed character count for it's column?

Comment: Show the update/insert query. That is actually the essential part

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place - you'e looking for _existing_ data that's too big.  What you need to look at is what data is being _added_ to the table.  Look at the `UPDATE`/`INSERT` statement and the values there.

Comment: The data that is too big to be put in the column won't be in the column because it's too big for the column Your UPDATE or INSERT statement is loading data into the table, and it's that data that it's loading that contains the data that is too big. [Also this is a very well known PIA error from MS Sql Server](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/339410/) where it just tells you that somethings too big and doesn't even bother telling you which column it's too big for. They've been meaning to get around to fix it since 2008.

Comment: The existing data cannot be too big, as it already has been inserted successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Is there a way to query the db for values in all columns that overrun the max allowed character count for it's column?***

As the other comments point out the problem is not with the data in your destination table but with the data you are trying to insert / update.

*However*, if you are inserting / updating data that was selected from a different table these queries may be useful for you. Mostly they were just fun to write.

Replace the `#MAX_LENGTH#` placeholder and the two `#TABLE_NAME#` placeholders and this will give you **any offending values in the table**.

```
declare @dyn varchar(max)
select @dyn = 'select null as [Column], null as [Value], null as [Lenght] '
select @dyn = @dyn 
+ 'union select ''' + name + ''', cast(' + name + ' as varchar(max)), len(' + name + ')
   from #TABLE_NAME#
   where len(' + name + ') > #MAX_LENGTH#'
from sys.columns c
where c.object_id = object_id('#TABLE_NAME#')
exec(@dyn)
```

Replace the two `#TABLE_NAME#` placeholders and this will show you the **max length of the values in each column of your table**.

```
declare @dyn varchar(max)
set @dyn = 'select 0 x'
select @dyn  = @dyn + ', max(len(' + name + ')) as [' + name + ']'
from sys.columns c
where c.object_id = object_id('#TABLE_NAME#')
exec(@dyn  + 'from #TABLE_NAME#')
```

Answer (score 1):

1. This error occurs because in the insert/update statement(s) there are value(s) that exceed the maximum number of characters allowed by the destination column(s). HOWEVER, the insert/update will succeed, the thing is that the value will be truncated to the max allowed characters. So if you define a VARCHAR(100) and you insert/update 101 characters then the last character will be left behind.
2. You can't see via a query or something if there are values that exceed the max number of allowed characters in a column because SQL Server doesn't store and hide the exceeding characters or something.. it just stores how many characters you tell it to store.
3. If you have columns where the values are in an unknown range you could use VARCHAR(MAX).

Comment: Thank you, sir.  It ended up being that a trigger was set to insert values into a column in an audit table.  The column didn't exist.